# Find closest branch based on distance between coordinates

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables in Teradata.

Table 1 - Login:

| Customer ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 44.5 | 66.41 |
| B | 12.3 | 62.21 |
| C | 12.3 | 42.21 |
| A | 22.3 | 52.21 |
| C | 92.3 | 2.21 |
| A | 44.5 | 66.41 |
| A | 44.5 | 66.41 |

Table 2 - Location:

| Branch Code | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.5 | 16.41 |
| 2 | 33.3 | 22.21 |
| 3 | 52.3 | 42.21 |

There's no relationship between both. I want to create a table that finds a customer's closest distance between themselves from table 1 and any of the branches in table 2. The data from table 1 is just the geolocation of a customer that logins in so a customer can have multiple records. I want, for every customer, the closest branch to them based on distance between the coords and **based on the number of logins from that location** - so the location from which they logged in the most, that's what I want to run against the branches and find the branch closest to it.

So the new table will look like this. Customer A (logged in 3 times from the same location) is closest to branch 2, etc.

| Customer ID | Closest To |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

What I first thought to do it cast the latitudes and longitudes as ST_GEOMETRY (Point(lat, long)), then find the distances, but I wasn't sure how to link both tables or do every combination of customer (or the customer's location with the most log ins) and branch. Still very new to Teradata.

What I tried:

```
SELECT customer_id, CAST('POINT(' || latitude || ', ' || longitude || ')' AS ST_GEOMETRY) AS loc1
FROM login

SELECT branch_code, CAST('POINT(' || latitude || ', ' || longitude || ')' AS ST_GEOMETRY) AS loc2
FROM location
```

What I basically want `loc1.ST_SphericalDistance(loc2)` but the thing I'm struggling with is 'joining' both tables and trying all the combinations.

**EDIT**:

I think I've done the initial part. This cross joins both tables and finds the distance for every customer (non-unique).

```
SELECT g.customer_id, l.branch_code, g.loc1.ST_SphericalDistance(l.loc2) AS distance
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, CAST('POINT(' || latitude || ', ' || longitude || ')' AS ST_GEOMETRY) AS loc1
    FROM login) AS g
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT branch_code, CAST('POINT(' || latitude || ', ' || longitude || ')' AS ST_GEOMETRY) AS loc2
    FROM location) AS l
```

If I group by `customer_id` and `branch_code`, and find the *minimum* distance, would that work? Don't have access to the the data at the moment.

Comment: Can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: So which piece are you struggling with?

Comment: I updated my post. The thing that I'm struggling with is how to link both tables and then calculate for each customer, the distance between the their Login record and every branch.

Comment: In theory, yes,  You could do something like `qualify row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by distance) = 1` to get the minimum distance for each customer

Comment: Yes, almost exactly what I want, thank you. So if I now want to only calculate the distance for the coordinates with the most logins from, I would have to change the first table to group by `loc1`, so `SELECT customer_id, CAST('POINT(' || latitude || ', ' || longitude || ')' AS ST_GEOMETRY) AS loc1, COUNT(*) AS n_logins FROM login) GROUP BY 1, 2` then somehow only take the largest count per loc1 per customer, but not sure how that could be done. Does that make sense?

Comment: Use a subquery (CTE or derived table) to GROUP BY customer and location and append a COUNT column, then use QUALIFY to limit to the most frequent row, and finally join that one selected location to the branch table to find the nearest.

Comment: Would the CTE look something like this? 
`select customer_id, CAST('POINT(' || latitude || ', ' || longitude || ')' as ST_GEOMETRY) as loc1, count(*) as n_logins
from login
group by 1, 2
qualify rank() over (order by n_logins desc) = 1`. 
I think rank makes sense here but is there a more standard way to limit to the most frequent row? **EDIT**: I guess `qualify row_number() over (order by n_logins desc) = 1` works as well.